# C# equivalent of typeof for fields

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

With reflection, you can look up a class from a string at run time, but you can also say typeof(Foo) and get compile time type checking, auto completion etc.

If what you want is a field not a class, you can look it up from a string at runtime, but if you want compile time type checking etc., is there anyway to say something like fieldof(Foo.Bar)? I know the name of both the class and the field in advance, and I want to be able to refer to the field at compile time rather than with a run-time string lookup.

edit: An example of what I want to use this for, say I've got a list of objects that may have been read from a database, and I want to display them in a DataGridView, but I only want displayed columns for certain fields. I'd like to write a method something like:

```
void DisplayData(object[] objs, params FieldInfo[] fields)
```

and be able to call it like

```
DisplayData(accounts, fieldof(Account.Name), fieldof(Account.Email));
```

That sort of idea.

Comment: A small piece of code to illustrate your question will help you get better answers

Comment: it sounds like you might be pulling the same type of class from multiple assemblies.  If so you might want to consider using an interface and doing your compile time type checking against that.  Then you can assign the instance variable to the dynamically loaded assembly and all will be well.

Comment: gbogumil - just the one assembly, but several places in the code where I want to do a certain operation on different fields of different classes, and therefore need to be able to specify which fields. I've added a code sample that hopefully might clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get rid of string literals using expressions

```
public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpression = null;

    if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
    {
        memberExpression = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
    }
    else if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
    {
        memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    }

    return memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
}

// usage:
PropertyInfo p = GetProperty<MyClass>(x => x.MyCompileTimeCheckedPropertyName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not for fields.
The closest you can get is a 'using alias' which allows you to specify alternative names for types:
e.g., using foo = System.Collections.Generic.List;